# Newsletter tracking image Outlook

Tags: outlook, tracking, newsletter

I have a newsletter system that keeps track of the people who read it. Although this function works only if permission is given to download the images. But this is not my problem at this time.

My problem is that when I open an newsletter in Outlook (2010) and I give permission to download the images, my system doesn't register this view. But when I open the same newsletter in gMail, it works without any problem. Even when I use Outlook to save the e-mail to a HTML file and I open this file, a new view is registered. The page that save's the view and renders an 1x1 image, doesn't return any errors and no errors can be found in the Apache logs.

The strange thing is that it still worked until a week ago. But even if I put backups of the code, it still doesn't work....

The image url is build up with an base64 encodes string, for example:
http://domain.com/tracker/eyJtYWlsaW5nSWQiOiI4MjQiLCJjb250YWN0SWQiOjM3MzA5LCJjaHVuayI6ImIyYmNiNzhkNjAyMmVmNzQ0NmM4ZDA0YzU1ZGZhMTY0In0=/
In this encodes string, I have a JSON string that contains the newsletter id, a contact id and a MD5 string which I use to validate the data.

I run of ideas what to do to fix or debug this issue. Does anyone have a tip or even better, a solution? :) It it possible that Microsoft updated Outlook to prevent it from downloading this kind of images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just happen to resolve this issue. The cause appeared to be fairly simple, but very difficult to detect.

When saving data about a user, I also requested the user-agent. In the database, I had a varchar (255) field in use for this information. However, the user-agent Outlook proved to be more than 255 characters. So this resulted in an error message from the database so that no image was generated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you are sending correct MIME
2. I suggest using extensions in url example: .png .jpg
3. Try different domain.

Comment: See my other answer for some more details about the code. couldn't get the code block in this comment field :)

Comment: Check file encoding. I had too many errors with UTF8 with BOM. I always make sure to have "UTF8 without BOM". Can you post headers send by server?

Comment: De response header:

Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:99
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Sun, 19 May 2013 07:21:02 GMT
Expires:Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=1, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

I also discovered it probably has something to do with a combination of Outlook and IE. A colleague has Outlook 2012 and IE8, I can track his data. I have IE10 and Outlook 2012, and my e-mail can't be tracked. I also can't save the tracking image from Outlook. Outlook states inval. img

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for generating the image:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 Ok');                      
header("Content-type: image/png");                      

$trackerImage = imagecreate(1, 1);
$bgColor = imagecolorallocate($trackerImage, 255, 255, 255);
imagepng($trackerImage);
imagedestroy($trackerImage);
```

This always worked until a hardware crash of the server 2 weeks ago... The hosting company claimes nothing has been changed to the servers configuration.

I already tried adding an extions to the image path, but that didn't make a difference for Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the HTML code to display the image as if it's a larger image. Or even better, just display a normal image along.